# How to remove link in comment of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've just created new website by Wordpress. Everything is in standard. when a user comment on my website they also can put a to their website.

[image]

There are a lot of competitor spam comment to link to their website. i don't know how to remove this link from comments? 
My dust buster website review is :http://dustbuster-review.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter named `comment_form_default_fields`. Add below code to your active theme’s **functions.php** file.

```
function disable_comment_url($fields) { 
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','disable_comment_url');
```